# Hibernate: Have a field that is not-peristed but can be pulled from DB?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entity, transient

I am the following `Hibernate` Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "status")
@Table(name = "status")
public class Status implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "status_id")
    private Integer statusId;


    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name = "status_label")
    private String statusLabel;

    @JsonProperty
    @Transient
    private String statusOrigin;

}
```

`statusOrigin` is transient as it is **not** a column in the `status` table.

This works fine for creating the object with only `statusId` and `statusLabel` fields as expected.

*However* when I want to return the Status object to the front end with a join query which populates all 3 fields it does not work as `statusOrigin` is transient.

How can I do the following:

1. keep the create functionality as it is
2. Ensure that statusOrigin field is populated from the results of the join query and sent to UI

Comment: How are you populating the field `statusOrigin` using join query in SELECT clause? What's the value you're expecting to come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add insertable and updatable false to the field

```
@Column(name="statusOrigin",insertable=false,updatable=false)
```